# Issue with Handlebars hide/show button onclick

Tags: jquery, html, json, handlebars.js, mustache

I am trying to get the details from the JSON and got succeed with it, but when I am trying to hide the phone number element by default and reveal with onclick button, it's just working for the first Doctor DIV, but not all divs..

I want to make the phone number hidden by default and reveal it by the user onclick button even?

```
      <div class="page-wrap">
    <h1>Handlebars Tutorial</h1>
    <div id="docs-container"></div>
  </div>

  <script id="docsTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  {{#each doctors}}
    <div class="pet">
      <div class="photo-column">
        <img src="{{Image}}">
      </div>
      <div class="info-column">
        <h2>{{DoctorName}}</h2>
  <p>Designation: {{Qualification}}</p>
        <p id="tohide">Phone: {{Phone}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  {{/each}}
  </script>
```

How can I make this possible and here is my fiddle I am trying to achieve with [Live Example](https://jsfiddle.net/45fs64p2/3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i do not see any button in your code. see this example and you can modify it.

```
$('.btn_phn').on('click', function(){
    $(this).prev('.tohide').show();
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/45fs64p2/4/

Comment: i updated the code with show phone element on click of a button. But the problem is it is revealing all the phone elements instead of that single doctor DIV. Here is the updated fiddle link [link] https://jsfiddle.net/45fs64p2/3/